# 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am facing an issue bringing up my fabric network.

```
Error: got unexpected status: FORBIDDEN -- implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Writers' sub-policies to be satisfied: permission denied
```

I cannot see how to solve.
The configuration is very simple but the problem seems related to policies.

I already tried to bring down the network and up, I tried removing volumes and everything that is said under other threads, but cannot solve.
I bringed up a network many times but never faced issue like this.

Also, the certificates have been regenerated from scratch, the sk file has been modified into the yml file, and the config file contains the artefacts for the network.
Essentially, I can bring down all the dockers but as soon as the script run this command

```
  docker exec -e $CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID -e $CORE_MSP_CONFIG_PATH $CLI peer channel create -o $ORDERER1:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
```

so it tries to create the channel, it fails.

I share also the configtx file that should be involved in the issue>

configtx.yaml

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
            - Host: peer1.org1.example.com
              Port: 8051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    Policies:
        # Readers:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Writers:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # Admins:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 500ms

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 15

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 kb

    Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
        Brokers:
           # - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    Policies:
        # Readers:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Writers:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # Admins:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        # BlockValidation:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        # Readers:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        # Writers:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        # Admins:
        #     Type: ImplicitMeta
        #     Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
    OneOrgChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
```

EDIT:
Updated confixtx after your comments:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

---
################################################################################
#
#   Section: Organizations
#
#   - This section defines the different organizational identities which will
#   be referenced later in the configuration.
#
################################################################################
Organizations:

    # SampleOrg defines an MSP using the sampleconfig.  It should never be used
    # in production but may be used as a template for other definitions
    - &OrdererOrg
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: OrdererOrg

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: OrdererMSP

        # MSPDir is the filesystem path which contains the MSP configuration
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP.admin')"

    - &Org1
        # DefaultOrg defines the organization which is used in the sampleconfig
        # of the fabric.git development environment
        Name: Org1MSP

        # ID to load the MSP definition as
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
        # For organization policies, their canonical path is usually
        #   /Channel/<Application|Orderer>/<OrgName>/<PolicyName>
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"

        AnchorPeers:
            # AnchorPeers defines the location of peers which can be used
            # for cross org gossip communication.  Note, this value is only
            # encoded in the genesis block in the Application section context
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
            - Host: peer1.org1.example.com
              Port: 8051

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Application
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for application related parameters
#
################################################################################
Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the application side of the network
    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

################################################################################
#
#   SECTION: Orderer
#
#   - This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for orderer related parameters
#
################################################################################
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults

    # Orderer Type: The orderer implementation to start
    # Available types are "solo" and "kafka"
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    # Batch Timeout: The amount of time to wait before creating a batch
    BatchTimeout: 500ms

    # Batch Size: Controls the number of messages batched into a block
    BatchSize:

        # Max Message Count: The maximum number of messages to permit in a batch
        MaxMessageCount: 15

        # Absolute Max Bytes: The absolute maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch.
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB

        # Preferred Max Bytes: The preferred maximum number of bytes allowed for
        # the serialized messages in a batch. A message larger than the preferred
        # max bytes will result in a batch larger than preferred max bytes.
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 kb

   # Kafka:
        # Brokers: A list of Kafka brokers to which the orderer connects
        # NOTE: Use IP:port notation
       # Brokers:
           # - 127.0.0.1:9092

    # Organizations is the list of orgs which are defined as participants on
    # the orderer side of the network
    Organizations:

    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        # BlockValidation specifies what signatures must be included in the block
        # from the orderer for the peer to validate it.
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

################################################################################
#
#   CHANNEL
#
#   This section defines the values to encode into a config transaction or
#   genesis block for channel related parameters.
#
################################################################################
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    # Policies defines the set of policies at this level of the config tree
    # For Channel policies, their canonical path is
    #   /Channel/<PolicyName>
    Policies:
        # Who may invoke the 'Deliver' API
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        # Who may invoke the 'Broadcast' API
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        # By default, who may modify elements at this config level
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

################################################################################
#
#   Profile
#
#   - Different configuration profiles may be encoded here to be specified
#   as parameters to the configtxgen tool
#
################################################################################
Profiles:

    OneOrgOrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
    OneOrgChannel:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your client an administrator of Org1?

Have you configured NodeOUs (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/msp.html#identity-classification)?

You can try without NodeOUs, which is less restrictive, by changing your Org1 policies to...

```
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.member')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
```

...and regenerating the required stuff (genesis block, channel transactions, etc.).

You can uncomment the rest of policies.

Comment: I did what you said: uncommented policies, inserted  the Org1 policies as you said, but I get the same error.

Comment: I just posted an updated version of the configtx file, check it

Comment: Then, my first question, is your client correctly configured (MSP, environment variables...) as an Org1 client?

Comment: Also, so can try to set `FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG` in your peer and copy the previous lines to the error, that show how every MSP and role is checked. `docker logs -f --tail 100 my-peer-container 2>&1 | grep ERROR -B25` (maybe `WARN` instead of `ERROR`).

Comment: I created the network and I used `docker logs -f --tail 100 my-peer-container 2>&1 | grep ERROR -B25` on my orderer and peer also with WARN and get nothing. Then I used  `docker exec -e $CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID -e $CORE_MSP_CONFIG_PATH $CLI peer channel create -o $ORDERER1:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx` which is the command that makes the error. Using the command
`docker logs -f --tail 100 orderer.example.com 2>&1 | grep WARN -B25` brings me to this error: https://prnt.sc/pzmly3

Comment: So, your client (the one executing `peer channel create`) does not fulfill the Writer policy of any orderer or organization belonging the channel. or at least it is not signing the request as it is.

Comment: Copy and paste (in text) the certificate just before the log you captured so we can analyze who is signing the request.

Comment: The client should be the cli, basing on what you say, becuase the command is cli peer channel create. The certificate is too long so I put image http://prntscr.com/pznsr8

Comment: Long for you to copy, longer for me to type in a file so I can check it via openssl.

Comment: Ok I copy pasted it, find it here: pastebin.com/Tck7CnkS

Answer (score 1):

OK. From your logs (when something fails, look at the logs):

```
2019-11-20 15:45:04.331 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 2e7 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers ==
```

Thus `/Channel/Orderer/OrdererOrg/Writers` is being evaluated.

The certificate signing the request is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So lets decode it:

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in cert.pem
```

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            be:6b:90:13:4f:2e:47:1c:41:18:4f:d0:fb:2e:61:09
        Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
        Issuer: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, O = org1.example.com, CN = ca.org1.example.com
        Validity
            Not Before: Nov 20 15:33:00 2019 GMT
            Not After : Nov 17 15:33:00 2029 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = California, L = San Francisco, CN = Admin@org1.example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey
                Public-Key: (256 bit)
                pub:
                    04:27:5e:64:94:5f:96:29:1e:51:46:93:8a:ec:ab:
                    3a:7d:62:e4:d9:73:67:d8:f5:71:83:c7:d6:2a:2f:
                    20:90:e8:6b:29:4a:db:98:ac:ee:73:3a:dd:23:2c:
                    6a:a3:ca:2b:9e:40:32:54:3e:d9:ed:51:a8:86:04:
                    54:e3:ed:df:d2
                ASN1 OID: prime256v1
                NIST CURVE: P-256
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:64:E5:3E:F4:37:51:59:32:88:73:F3:B3:5E:26:0D:51:A1:CA:14:57:13:E9:E9:25:AB:77:F8:3A:08:7B:AA:4C

    Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
         30:45:02:21:00:c9:f3:72:7a:81:7f:86:96:cf:66:70:65:32:
         33:fe:ee:9c:94:c8:8a:9f:a2:26:7c:6e:f1:c1:a3:24:fb:c7:
         75:02:20:6c:9c:78:01:33:b4:22:74:f6:9e:6d:55:2a:68:ea:
         38:2b:49:b6:be:55:33:0b:cb:5f:ae:a6:96:20:5e:f3:b8
```

It looks good, but the most important thing is the message:

```
2019-11-20 15:45:04.332 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 2ea Principal deserialization failure (the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority) for identity 0
```

**The orderer is not recognising the CA signing your request**. Are you totally sure that your client's certificate (the one received above) is signed by the same CA that was configured into your `configtx.yaml` (`crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/cacerts/whateveritiscalled.pem`) before executing `configtxgen` commands to generate the genesis block (and other stuff) and running your orderer. I bet it is not. At some time you have run `cryptogen` again and your client's certificate is signed by other (a newer or older) CA than the one specified for the Org1 MSP in the `configtx.yaml` at the time of generating the genesis block used by your orderer.

Comment: What I do is: run a generate script that generates crypto-config. I obviously modify the in the docker-compose.yml the part of FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE in which I have to put the correct path and private key contained in: `./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/` . Then I run the configure script that generates my config folder with genesis block and other files. I run the network. The docker-compose is this: https://pastebin.com/JgkbxPCZ the template is substituted with sep with the correct PKey. Network creates correctly but when I create the channel I get the error

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the ChannelDefaults to the genesis block something like this:

```
Profiles:

ThreeOrgsOrdererGenesis:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Orderer:
        <<: *OrdererDefaults
...
```

Comment: I did it too, but it doesnt work. I will post my updated configtx.yaml, check it

Comment: I just posted an updated version of the configtx file, check it